# Qt installer unregister filetype on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry, qt-installer

I'm working with Qt installer to deploy my software on Windows machines. So far, everything works as expected: I can install stuff and **register file extensions** to be launched with my software.

Let's say my app is named *MyApp* and the extension is *.myapp*.

Here is the code that I use to do so in an *installscript.qs* script:

```
Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
   component.createOperations();
   if (systemInfo.productType === "windows") {
      component.addOperation(
         "RegisterFileType",
         "myapp",
         "@TargetDir@\\MyApp.exe" + " \"%1\"",
         "Company - MyApp file",
         "application/this.is.awesome",
         "@TargetDir@\\MyApp.exe" + "," + 1,
         "ProgId=Company.MyApp." + "myapp"
      );
   }
}
```

Now, when I uninstall the app using the Qt's uninstaller, it correctly removes the files from my PC but **the filetype registration remains in Windows' settings** and when reinstallating the app again, the installer simply adds another filetype registration regardless of the existing one(s). So at this point if I install/uninstall my app 20 times, I'll have 20 copies of the same filetype registration.

Any idea what's going on ?